# Is there a way to override properties' description and example in OAS3?

Tags: openapi

I have been looking for resources about inheritance in OAS3 but the closest i get is https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md and the above did not have answer i am looking for.

This is the working example

```
components:
  schemas:
    Pet:
      properties:
        no_legs:
          description: "Number of legs"
          type: number
          example: 4
    Duck:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          properties:
            no_legs:
              example: 2
      properties:
        no_legs:
          description: 'Number of webbed feet'
```

Failing example that was inspired by the spec

```
    Duck:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          properties:
            no_legs:
              description: 'Number of webbed feet'
              example: 2
```

My questions are

- Is the overriding feature i am looking at available/supported?
- If so what is the appropriate way of doing it?

I understood that i can use composition to tackle this issue but i will have a lot of the definition being repeated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's essentially the way to go about overriding properties. What sort of error are you getting on your failing example? It works just fine at https://editor.swagger.io/ at least. Did you remember to specify `openapi: 3.0.0` at the root of your document?

Note that the following two definitions are identical:

```
Duck:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
    - type: object
      properties:
        no_legs:
          description: 'Number of webbed feet'
          example: 2
```

```
Duck:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
  properties:
    no_legs:
      description: 'Number of webbed feet'
      example: 2
```

Comment: Your second example there might be accepted by many tools, but it is **not** syntactically correct [according to the OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/specification/#:~:text=In%20both%20the%20oneOf%20and%20anyOf%20use%20cases,%20all%20possible%20schemas%20MUST%20be%20listed%20explicitly), which permits `allOf` only *in place of* a Schema Object, and does not permit two Schema Objects to co-exist.